# Python - Opening a File in a Text Editor with Minimal Imports

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to open a file. And, it works.

I understand that we use `from sys import argv` to import just the function argv from the sys module.

The code I used to open a file is

```
from sys import argv
import subprocess

script, filename = argv

txt = open (filename)

print "Here's your file %r: " % filename
proc = subprocess.Popen(['scratch-text-editor', 'sample_file'])
proc.wait()
```

I tried using `from subprocess import Popen`, but it throws an error.

```
Here's your file 'sample_file': 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex12.py", line 9, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['scratch-text-editor', 'sample_file'])
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

How can I make it work using `from subprocess import Popen`. What am I missing here? Isn't this the better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
from a import b
```

you can access it just like

```
b()
```

and not by doing

```
a.b()
```

In your case, just call

```
Popen()
```

Instead of

```
subprocess.Popen()
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you. If someone can think of a more apt question title; please change it.